# Java sql errors with preparedstatement

Tags: java, mysql

```
Testcase: testKlantVerwijderen(Main.ApplicationTest):   Caused an ERROR
SQL-exception in zoekKlant - statementcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from klant where naam = '2' and voornaam = 'test' and geboortedatum = '1998-08-1' at line 1
exception.DBException: SQL-exception in zoekKlant - statementcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from klant where naam = '2' and voornaam = 'test' and geboortedatum = '1998-08-1' at line 1
    at database.KlantDB.zoekKlant(KlantDB.java:116)
    at Main.Application.klantVerwijderen(Application.java:79)
    at Main.ApplicationTest.testKlantVerwijderen(ApplicationTest.java:101)
```

My code:

```
public Klant zoekKlant(Klant k) throws DBException {
  Klant returnKlant = null;
  // connectie tot stand brengen (en automatisch sluiten)
  try (Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();) {
     // preparedStatement opstellen (en automtisch sluiten)
     try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "select * from klant from klant where naam = ? and voornaam = ? and geboortedatum = ? ");) {

        stmt.setString(1, k.getNaam());
        stmt.setString(2, k.getVoornaam());
        stmt.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(k.getGeboorteDatum()));
        stmt.execute();
        // result opvragen (en automatisch sluiten)
        try (ResultSet r = stmt.getResultSet()) {
           if (r.next()) {
              Klant klant = new Klant();
              klant.setId(r.getInt("id"));
              klant.setNaam(r.getString("naam"));
              klant.setVoornaam(r.getString("voornaam"));
              klant.setGeboorteDatum(r.getDate("geboortedatum").toLocalDate());
              klant.setOpmerking(r.getString("opmerking"));
              klant.setDebetstandLimiet(r.getBigDecimal("debetstand_limiet"));
              if (r.getByte("actief") == 0)
              {
                  klant.setActief(false);
              }
              else{
                  klant.setActief(true);
              }
              returnKlant = klant;
           }
           return returnKlant;

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
           throw new DBException("SQL-exception in zoekKlant - resultset"+ sqlEx);
        }
     } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        throw new DBException("SQL-exception in zoekKlant - statement"+ sqlEx);
     }
  } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
     throw new DBException(
        "SQL-exception in zoekKlant - connection");
  }

}
```

My database:

```
1   id  int(11)         Nee Geen    AUTO_INCREMENT  Veranderen Veranderen   Verwijderen Verwijderen 
Primaire sleutel Primaire sleutel
Unieke waarde Unieke waarde
Index Index
Ruimtelijk Ruimtelijk
Meer
    2   naam    varchar(64) latin1_swedish_ci       Nee Geen        Veranderen Veranderen   Verwijderen Verwijderen 
Primaire sleutel Primaire sleutel
Unieke waarde Unieke waarde
Index Index
Ruimtelijk Ruimtelijk
Meer
    3   voornaam    varchar(32) latin1_swedish_ci       Nee Geen        Veranderen Veranderen   Verwijderen Verwijderen 
Primaire sleutel Primaire sleutel
Unieke waarde Unieke waarde
Index Index
Ruimtelijk Ruimtelijk
Meer
    4   geboortedatum   date            Nee Geen        Veranderen Veranderen   Verwijderen Verwijderen 
Primaire sleutel Primaire sleutel
Unieke waarde Unieke waarde
Index Index
Ruimtelijk Ruimtelijk
Meer
    5   opmerking   text    latin1_swedish_ci       Ja  NULL        Veranderen Veranderen   Verwijderen Verwijderen 
Primaire sleutel Primaire sleutel
Unieke waarde Unieke waarde
Index Index
Ruimtelijk Ruimtelijk
Meer
    6   debetstand_limiet   double          Nee Geen        Veranderen Veranderen   Verwijderen Verwijderen 
Primaire sleutel Primaire sleutel
Unieke waarde Unieke waarde
Index Index
Ruimtelijk Ruimtelijk
Meer
    7   actief  tinyint(1)          Nee Geen
```

So basically somehow there is something wrong with my preparedstatement. I don't quite understand what though? It should be working correctly but it isn't, which is quite strange. I simply want to select all the fields that match my condition, and I'm pretty sure this is what the query should look like, but for some reason it isn't. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Would be much aprreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cause you have repeated the `FROM` clause twice in your `SELECT` query like `from klant from klant`. See below pointed

```
 try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select * from klant from klant where naam = ? and voornaam = ?
                         ^.... HERE
```

Comment: @user3227070, consider accepting the answer if it helped.